# iPhone sending multi-part texts as 60 character parts. Unicode punctuation to blame?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, sms

From one specific iPhone user, I keep receiving multipart texts for small messages. Instead of 160 characters each, I'm getting about 60. It looks as though if any part of the message contains a Unicode character, the entire message is chopped up as if each character is 2 bytes. I've investigated slightly, and sure enough, the apostrophes I've been receiving are `’`.

I have looked at her phone keyboard and can't really figure anything out. How should I proceed to correct this?

Comment: perhaps rather flippantly, I'd suggest using iMessage instead of SMS

Comment: Is it US keyboard you're using?

Comment: I would also suggest checking to see if they are using the built-in keyboard or a 3rd-party